# corner_fast return from skimage

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I just tried `corner_fast` form [skimage](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.corner_fast) and it seems to work pretty well for corner detection:

```
from skimage.feature import corner_fast
np.random.seed(2018)
img = np.random.normal(size=(20, 20))
img_response = corner_fast(img, n=12, threshold=0.0)
```

The FAST algorithm is explained in numerous places in the web. However, these explanations suggest FAST should return a boolean value (corner or not-corner).

Yet, `img_response` is a float array. I guess these numbers correspond to how "cornery" a specific pixel is, but, how are they computed? What do they really represent?

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is right, the response image is a sort of accumulator, the higher the value, the more "cornery" the pixel is.

To extract the corners location, you can call the function `corner_peaks` on the result returned by `corner_fast`

About the how to is it computed, the documentation gives these two references:

- [1]   Edward Rosten and Tom Drummond “Machine Learning for high-speed corner detection”, http://www.edwardrosten.com/work/rosten_2006_machine.pdf
- [2]   Wikipedia, “Features from accelerated segment test”, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_from_accelerated_segment_test

Finally, just know that `scikit-image` is open source and you can therefore go see the details of the code itself https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/tree/master/skimage